# Where a should inject service, which should be visible in all app? (angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-injection

I want to create `NewService`. And I want to have possibility to call it from all application?

Where I should inject it in SharedModule (module which exports all reusable modules) or in AppModule ( main module of my application)

```
@NgModule({

  providers: [
     // Here?
  ]
})
```

Comment: the best place would probably be in the angular bootstrap method

Comment: Don't think so. That was valid before `NgModule` was introduced but now I wouldn't suggest adding to `bootstrap` if there is not a specific reason.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer good point. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you add it to the `AppModule` directly or to a feature module as long as the module is not lazy loaded.

Lazy loaded modules have their own root scope and providers added there are only visible to the lazy loaded module.

Comment: Sure. Pack directives, pipes, and services together if they build a reusable feature together and then add the module to `imports: [...]` where you want to use this feature. This is the intended use of `NgModule` (in addition to lazy loading).

Comment: So, I should add NewService to   exports: [...] in SharedModule and import SharedModule to another modules.
But I can not use NewService in another module?
What else have I to do?

Comment: Services should be enough to add to `providers: []` only directives, components, and pipes and re-exported modules need to be added to `exports: []` and then add this module to `imports: []` of the AppModule or some other module where you want to use it.